# "Would have" and "would have no"

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, expressions

Could you describe about "would have ~ed" & "would have not ~ed".

I know *would* has the several meanings. But when I was talking with one of my friend who is a native speaker and in this following conversation with him I couldn't understand the meanings he said.

> A: I bought strong cheese this morning. Let’s eat it! You like it, don’t you? Because You have stayed in Germany for several months and Germany is famous for cheese.
>
> B: Not really. Because when I was living there I tried a strong cheese and felt so bad afterwards. So I **wouldn't have purchased** any cheese in Germany at that time.

When I heard it, I got it  that he  has never  bought  any cheese there.

If so, what’s the differences between "I wouldn’t have bought" and "I have never bought"?

I would like to know  the accurate meaning.

Also I found the description like my question online below.

> Q:
>
> Hello All,
>
> Could you tell me if I say "He would have done that" what exactly does it mean?
>
> Does it mean that "he just start to do that before something happens and that make him stop to do it.
>
> A:
>
> We need more context, Farheen.
>
> (1) He "would" have done that = he is the sort of person to do such a thing.
>
> (2) He would have done "that" = He would have done something different.
>
> (2) "He" would have done that = He must have been the person who did it.
>
> Can you give us more of the text?

In this Q&A, the answered person answered the question in 3 conditions and I've thought

if *would* is replaced with *would not* ,these all sentence will turn into negative condition.

For example in (1)  He "would not" have done that = he is “not” the sort of person to do such a thing.  Is this also right?

If so can I say the following sentence as one of my customs?

For example:

> I wouldn’t have shoplifted in my whole life.
>
> I wouldn’t have had a relationship with a lady, not even once

And I have another question.

what’s the differences (1) &(2)blow?

> (1)He would have drunk coffee when he was young. = he is the sort of person to do such a thing.
>
> (2)He would drink coffee when he was young.

Comment: Not relevant to the question as such, but I don't think any native speaker would ever say *"I tried a strong cheese and felt so bad for it."*

Comment: Unless it was screaming, "Don't eat me!" lol!

Answer (score 2):

"I wouldn't have bought any cheese" is expressed as a deduction (as in the discussion you follow up with) "it's not likely I bought cheese", or "I'm not the sort of person to have bought cheese there".

The pragmatic implication in this sense is either "I don't remember for sure whether I ever bought cheese, but I can't believe I did", or possibly "You must see that I'm not the sort of person to buy cheese there".